# How much current Hold and WP SPI Flash pins can draw?

Tags: pcb-design, diodes, spi, schottky

In my design J14 is used as header to which I connect wires to an external programmer (DediProg) in order to program an SPI Flash (U25).

At the time of flashing, I don't want to supply voltage to (3V3AUX) gives power to a Host Controller which needs this flash ROM for functioning properly.

I want to use [BAT54WS](https://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/bat54ws.pdf) Schottky diode in order not to supply 3V3AUX voltage at the time the DediProg programmer is ON (VCC_DEDIPROG is high) and supplying voltage:

[image]

I'm using [PM25LV080B](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01co9t9pvj2xzgy/Flash%20SPI%208-16Mbit%20Pm25LV080B-016Bpdf_in_design.pdf?dl=0) Flash and I was wondering if the flash can draw so much current, in a way that the voltage on the diode would be too high such that the remained voltage would not be enough for the SPI flash to stay working.

According to the table and datasheet, there is no information about how much current WP# and HOLD# pins can draw. I only know that VCC draws up tp 30 mA.
at 30mA the voltage drop on the diode would around 500mV, which would leave 3.1V for the flash VCC. how do I know that the WP# and HOLD# pins don't pull the VCC voltage below 2.7v which is below the working range?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless called out explicitly, input pins will only draw up to I<sub>LI</sub> = 1 µA, as long as the applied voltage remains between the supply rails.

Comment: Nice! I thought about that too since it's a logic input that is connected to some transistor gate.